# NE555 + CD4017 Airplane Strobe Light with LDR

Tags: schematics, 555, light, blink, cd4017

Engineers! I have built a simple airplane strobe light using NE555 and CD4017 in order to flash two LED in a different pattern. I have added an LDR resistor with a transistor in order to switch OFF the strobe light during the day and switch it ON when night. So far so good, all works as expected except for one thing, when the light changes suddenly sometimes we get one of the LEDs stuck on the "ON" position and glowing where they should be OFF.

I have tried adding a capacitor between the LDR and VCC input - it didn't work.

I have tried adding a capacitor between the transistor Q2 base and resistor R8 - it didn't work.

Any ideas?

[Video](https://youtube.com/shorts/K_AW8A1b0Zw?si=d_lvlrK8YzGiaq5h) - **<-- See the Video in YouTube**

Schematic:

[image: NE555 schematics]
[image: CD4017 schematics]
[image: Breadboard prototype stuck on red]

EDIT: I have found a major mistake in the schematic and the breadboard.
According to my schematics I have connected one end of the LDR to VCC and another end to resistor R7 - from there goes to GND in junction between the LDR and R7, I have R8 - from there goes to the base of the transistor, BUT on my breadboard I have put the VCC end of the LDR to GND and it's working, therefore my schematics is wrong. Please see my updated schematics that is working on the breadboard but still get stuck sometimes.

[image: Updated schematics]

Comment: Why there is a big capacitor on the NE555 output / CD4017 clock input?

Comment: You can try an alternative design as shown here: https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/How_To_Make__Police_Strobe_light_using_555_timer_2.html

Answer (score 6):

The LED is getting stuck on because you're not also resetting the CD4017.

Comment: The 4017 will reset to the first output automatically after it has cycled through the 9 other outputs. The reset can be used to return to the first output early if required without cycling through all 10 outputs.

Comment: @user350400: Yes, but when the oscillator stops, the CD4017 can stop in any state. Three chances out of 10, one of the LEDs will remain on.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: Didn't work on the breadboard, used a 4.7K resistor.

Answer (score 4):

There should be a pull-up resistor (say 10k) between the 555's Reset (pin 4) and Vcc.

Also add a decoupling capacitor (4.7uF) between Vcc and ground close to the 555's pins 1 and 8.

You need to hold the 4017 in reset whenever the 555 is put into reset but unfortunatly the 555 is active reset low and the 4017 is active reset high so I would suggest using an op amp based inverting schmitt Trigger to invert the 555's reset signal for use by the 4017. The Schmitt will cater for the slowly changing RESET signal at the transistor's collector and cleanly switch the 4017's reset input. The switching threshold for the Schmitt trigger would need to be set to the same level as the level which brings the 555 out of reset which is a maximum of 1.0 V

Whenever the 4017 is held in reset, it's Q0 output is active (high) and so you can't use the Q0 output to drive an LED or the problem will persist. So, could you use Q1, Q2 and Q4 instead?

With regard to your previous edit - With both sides of the LDR effectively connected to ground I don't see how the light sensing side of your circuit can possibly work.

See below for a suggested circuit which should achieve your desired outcome.

On further reflection I realised that there is no need to hold the 555 in reset, it can always happily oscillate away. Whilst the 4017 is held in reset, the clock pulses will be ignored. I've swapped the positions of the LDR and resistor at the input to the circuit so that the 4017 is held in reset during daylight.

[image: LED flasher]

I have specified a NE555 (a bipolar version of the 555) in my design because that is what you have been using but it would be better to use a CMOS version, such as the ICM7555, instead. The CMOS version is the lower power version of the 555 and its output, when in an unloaded high state, reaches closer to Vcc than the bipolar version does. This gives better noise immunity when driving digital logic devices.

Comment: @SvetGEoff See edit

Comment: Yes, I was able to switch from pin Q0 to Q2 with no difference in light pattern (other pins make changes to the light pattern). I will do some more research about the schmitt Trigger and update the schematic.

Comment: @SvetGEoff What voltage is your Vcc?

Comment: I am using 5V :)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have noted the problem, but I'd suggest an alternative solution: have the right side of the LDR connect to Q8 of the 4017 rather than VDD.  That would ensure that no matter where during a ten-count cycle the LDR starts conducting enough to turn on Q2, the cycle would run to completion.  Approaches that involve resetting the 4017 may behave poorly under conditions that are right on the threshold of disabling circuit operation.  If e.g. the light from the first LED was enough to push the threshold over the edge, one could end up with the first LED repeatedly cycling on just long enough to reset the 4017.  Gating the 555's disable signal with Q8 would mean that if the 555 manages to run a cycle, it would run a complete "normal" cycle before the two cycles that illuminate LEDs and the idle cycles that should precede the next blink.